# TypeError: Test.findAll is not a function callinf Mongoose Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

This is my schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const testSchema = Schema({
    title: String,
    questions: [],
    user: Schema.Types.ObjectId
});

testSchema.methods.findAll = async function (){

    let tests = await this.find({});

    return tests;
}


module.exports = mongoose.model('Test',testSchema)
```

and I'm triyng to use it on this function

```
showMainPage = function(req, res){
    var tests = Test.findAll();
    console.log(tests);
    res.render('main/index.twig', {username:req.user.username});
}
```

But I get this error message

```
TypeError: Test.findAll is not a function
```

How can I access to the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added `findAll` as an instance method and not as a static one. If you wish to add a static method for a model then you can do this:

```
testSchema.statics.findAll = async function (){

    let tests = await this.find({});

    return tests;
}
```

See [Statics](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics)